# how to bypass SSL authentication URL connection wise in java?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpsurlconnection

I am creating a java application where I need to bypass SSL authentication  for **some URL connection, not for all URL connection**. Currently I am using the following code:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted (
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted (
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }
};
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()); 
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

In this code all URL connection skipping SSL authentication, until the application get restarted.

Is there any way so that we can skip SSL authentication check only for some URL connection, not for all URL connection?

Comment: If you don't want it secure why use HTTPS at all?

Comment: there was problem in my certificate in server side, so I want to bypass SSL authentication for temporary time of period.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory` globally on the class, cast your `URLConnection` instance into an `HttpsURLConnection` instance and use `setSSLSocketFactory(...)`.

Instead of bypassing all verification, it's better to use a specific truststore for these connections too, if you can, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/372643).