# Do a https client check with java or android

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I got a url with https, which has a common certification (which means this url could be visited from the browser and has a https security badge). Now I want to get the info from this url using HttpsUrlConnection, how can I do a certification check.

I am a SSL beginner, so I did some searching. And I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection/859271#859271), which is a self-signed check demo.

I'm wondering if the common https link should be checked like this. Does HttpsUrlConnection do a check, I found on the Android Developers:

> If an application wants to trust Certificate Authority (CA) certificates that are not part of the system, it should specify its own X509TrustManager via a SSLSocketFactory set on the HttpsURLConnection.

Does this means I don't need to check the server certificate if I can browse it from a web browser? Can I do a validation like the web browser does? And where can I find the trust store file, can I just make a default key store? Or anybody can tell me how to implement a TrustManager(I do want a validation, not a trust  manager that trust anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this information will help you [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e449)