# How load website in WebView JavaFX, if that asked *.pfx certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

I'm using `javafx.scene.web.WebView`. Other websites loads fine, but one give me clear white `WebView`. When I'm load it in Google Chrome, I see the window, that asking my installed certificate, I confirm, ant website loads. Certificate is in *.pfx file. How can I manually load certificate in java `WebView`?

Now I use just:

```
webEngine.load("https://www.**********.ru/");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection/859271#859271 Accepted answer should help you a lot!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [JavaFX WebView and Client Certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158872/javafx-webview-and-client-certificate), but cannot currently be closed as a duplicate as the duplicate has no answer.