# Getting RSA private key from PEM BASE64 Encoded private key file

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, x509, pkcs#8

I have a private key file (PEM BASE64 encoded). I want to use it else where to decrypt some other data. Below is the java class snippet to read the private key file and decode the BASE64 encoded data in it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import com.ibm.crypto.fips.provider.RSAPrivateKey;
import com.ibm.misc.BASE64Decoder;

public class GetPrivateKey {
    public static RSAPrivateKey get() throws Exception {
        File privateKeyFile = new File("privatekey.key");
        byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int) privateKeyFile.length()];
        new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile).read(encodedKey);
        ByteBuffer keyBytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBufferToByteBuffer(encodedKey.toString());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes.array());
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "IBMJCEFIPS");
        RSAPrivateKey pk = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        return pk;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrivateKey privKey = FormatMePlease.get();
        System.out.println(privKey.toString());
    }

}
```

I am getting the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.
at com.ibm.crypto.fips.provider.RSAKeyFactory.b(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.crypto.fips.provider.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)
at GetPrivateKey.get(GetPrivateKey.java:24)
at GetPrivateKey.main(GetPrivateKey.java:29)
```

The contents of the file `privatekey.key`

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Similar questions have been posted here, but those were of no help for me.
Almost all of them suggested using Bouncycastle provider which I cannot use as I'm restricted to using a FIPS compliant provider and I'm not sure if BC provider is FIPS compliant.

Comment: @user384706 I'm not sure if Bouncycastle is fips compliant.so am using IBMJCEFIPS provider.

Comment: The BC provider is not FIPS compliant. What is the first line of your PEM file, the line that starts "-----BEGIN"?

Comment: @GregS
The first line of the private.key file is
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Also see [Decrypting an OpenSSL PEM Encoded RSA private key with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35276820), [How to get the java.security.PrivateKey object from RSA Privatekey.pem file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7525679) and [Using a PEM encoded, encrypted private key to sign a message natively](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1580012). Some suggest to convert the private key to PKCS #8.

Answer (score 40):

This is PKCS#1 format of a private key. Try this code. It doesn't use Bouncy Castle or other third-party crypto providers. Just java.security and sun.security for DER sequece parsing. Also it supports parsing of a private key in PKCS#8 format (PEM file that has a header "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----").

```
import sun.security.util.DerInputStream;
import sun.security.util.DerValue;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public static PrivateKey pemFileLoadPrivateKeyPkcs1OrPkcs8Encoded(File pemFileName) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        // PKCS#8 format
        final String PEM_PRIVATE_START = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
        final String PEM_PRIVATE_END = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

        // PKCS#1 format
        final String PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_START = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
        final String PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_END = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

        Path path = Paths.get(pemFileName.getAbsolutePath());

        String privateKeyPem = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));

        if (privateKeyPem.indexOf(PEM_PRIVATE_START) != -1) { // PKCS#8 format
            privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.replace(PEM_PRIVATE_START, "").replace(PEM_PRIVATE_END, "");
            privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.replaceAll("\\s", "");

            byte[] pkcs8EncodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPem);

            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return factory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedKey));

        } else if (privateKeyPem.indexOf(PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_START) != -1) {  // PKCS#1 format

            privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.replace(PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_START, "").replace(PEM_RSA_PRIVATE_END, "");
            privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.replaceAll("\\s", "");

            DerInputStream derReader = new DerInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPem));

            DerValue[] seq = derReader.getSequence(0);

            if (seq.length < 9) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("Could not parse a PKCS1 private key.");
            }

            // skip version seq[0];
            BigInteger modulus = seq[1].getBigInteger();
            BigInteger publicExp = seq[2].getBigInteger();
            BigInteger privateExp = seq[3].getBigInteger();
            BigInteger prime1 = seq[4].getBigInteger();
            BigInteger prime2 = seq[5].getBigInteger();
            BigInteger exp1 = seq[6].getBigInteger();
            BigInteger exp2 = seq[7].getBigInteger();
            BigInteger crtCoef = seq[8].getBigInteger();

            RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(modulus, publicExp, privateExp, prime1, prime2, exp1, exp2, crtCoef);

            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

            return factory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        }

        throw new GeneralSecurityException("Not supported format of a private key");
    }
```

Comment: `DerInputStream` and `DerValue` are not anymore available starting from JDK 9.

Answer (score 39):

You will find below some code for reading *unencrypted* RSA keys encoded in the following formats:

- PKCS#1 PEM (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`)
- PKCS#8 PEM (`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`)
- PKCS#8 DER (binary)

It works with Java 7+ (and after 9) and doesn't use third-party libraries (like BouncyCastle) or internal Java APIs (like `DerInputStream` or `DerValue`).

```
private static final String PKCS_1_PEM_HEADER = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
private static final String PKCS_1_PEM_FOOTER = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
private static final String PKCS_8_PEM_HEADER = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
private static final String PKCS_8_PEM_FOOTER = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

public static PrivateKey loadKey(String keyFilePath) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    byte[] keyDataBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyFilePath));
    String keyDataString = new String(keyDataBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    if (keyDataString.contains(PKCS_1_PEM_HEADER)) {
        // OpenSSL / PKCS#1 Base64 PEM encoded file
        keyDataString = keyDataString.replace(PKCS_1_PEM_HEADER, "");
        keyDataString = keyDataString.replace(PKCS_1_PEM_FOOTER, "");
        return readPkcs1PrivateKey(Base64.decodeBase64(keyDataString));
    }

    if (keyDataString.contains(PKCS_8_PEM_HEADER)) {
        // PKCS#8 Base64 PEM encoded file
        keyDataString = keyDataString.replace(PKCS_8_PEM_HEADER, "");
        keyDataString = keyDataString.replace(PKCS_8_PEM_FOOTER, "");
        return readPkcs8PrivateKey(Base64.decodeBase64(keyDataString));
    }

    // We assume it's a PKCS#8 DER encoded binary file
    return readPkcs8PrivateKey(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyFilePath)));
}

private static PrivateKey readPkcs8PrivateKey(byte[] pkcs8Bytes) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "SunRsaSign");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8Bytes);
    try {
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected key format!", e);
    }
}

private static PrivateKey readPkcs1PrivateKey(byte[] pkcs1Bytes) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    // We can't use Java internal APIs to parse ASN.1 structures, so we build a PKCS#8 key Java can understand
    int pkcs1Length = pkcs1Bytes.length;
    int totalLength = pkcs1Length + 22;
    byte[] pkcs8Header = new byte[] {
            0x30, (byte) 0x82, (byte) ((totalLength >> 8) & 0xff), (byte) (totalLength & 0xff), // Sequence + total length
            0x2, 0x1, 0x0, // Integer (0)
            0x30, 0xD, 0x6, 0x9, 0x2A, (byte) 0x86, 0x48, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xF7, 0xD, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0x5, 0x0, // Sequence: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1, NULL
            0x4, (byte) 0x82, (byte) ((pkcs1Length >> 8) & 0xff), (byte) (pkcs1Length & 0xff) // Octet string + length
    };
    byte[] pkcs8bytes = join(pkcs8Header, pkcs1Bytes);
    return readPkcs8PrivateKey(pkcs8bytes);
}

private static byte[] join(byte[] byteArray1, byte[] byteArray2){
    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteArray1.length + byteArray2.length];
    System.arraycopy(byteArray1, 0, bytes, 0, byteArray1.length);
    System.arraycopy(byteArray2, 0, bytes, byteArray1.length, byteArray2.length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Mastercard/client-encryption-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mastercard/developer/utils/EncryptionUtils.java

Comment: This looks like best solution. does it have any drawbacks? is it safe to simply convert PKCS1 key to PKCS8 like this?

Comment: "does it have any drawbacks?" @krishnaTelgave, the best way to tell is to unit test this code with the data your application is supposed to handle

Comment: Thanks, your `readPkcs1PrivateKey` worked like a charm. Do you know by chance the `openssl` command equivalent?

Answer (score 37):

You've just published that private key, so now the whole world knows what it is. Hopefully that was just for testing.

EDIT: [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218774/238704) have noted that the openssl text header of the published key,  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----, indicates that it is PKCS#1. However, the actual Base64 contents of the key in question is PKCS#8. Evidently the OP copy and pasted the header and trailer of a PKCS#1 key onto the PKCS#8 key for some unknown reason. The sample code I've provided below works with PKCS#8 private keys.

Here is some code that will create the private key from that data. You'll have to replace the Base64 decoding with your IBM Base64 decoder.

```
public class RSAToy {

    private static final String BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
            + "MIIEuwIBADAN ...skipped the rest\n"
         // + ...   
         // + ... skipped the rest
         // + ...   
            + "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Remove the first and last lines

        String privKeyPEM = BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
        privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        System.out.println(privKeyPEM);

        // Base64 decode the data

        byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(privKeyPEM);

        // PKCS8 decode the encoded RSA private key

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        // Display the results

        System.out.println(privKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me, using your test key. Maybe you can test it using the Oracle JDK and another Base64 decoder, for example [this](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) one.

Comment: I'm using IBM JDK, and isn't there any other way to extract private key from a pem formatted key file...i couldn't find any good java documentation on this. Using Openssl one can convert a der to pem n vice-versa... my purpose is to do it using java only,reading a private key from pem..tried many ways but couldn't succeed...adding to my woes my code should be FIPS compliant. so i had to stick to IBM JDK which supports FIPS

Comment: @Venkat Madhav: I understand that you must use the IBM JDK. I was proposing that you *test* your code with the Oracle JDK just for the purpose of narrowing down where the problem is. If your code works with the Oracle JDK then we know that we have an IBM JDK issue that we have to work through. But if it doesn't work with the Oracle JDK then we know the problem lies somewhere in your code and not in the IBM JDK.

Comment: To convert a pem file to der in openssl, we use 
"openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in private.pem -outform DER -out private.der" command to get it done. Taking this as a reference, trying to map things from openssl to java. openssl pkcs8 argument is equivalent to PKCS8EncodedKeySpec in java.What for -topk8 parameter is used in openssl?

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
 at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @GregS, this is a nice bit of code but I'm not convinced that `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` signifies PKCS8 formatted keys. From my understanding, these are SSLeay formatted, which is causing the error for some users. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22218774/1554386

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: Thanks for your comment. I paid no attention to the headers and trailers, just the stuff inside which is clearly PKCS#8 encoded. To see this, just paste it into your favorite ASN.1 decoder. I like [lapo.it](http://lapo.it/asn1js/). Perhaps the OP cut-and-pasted different headers from different kinds of files? If so that will mislead others so your comment is quite appreciated.

Comment: You led me on the right path, but I had to use "openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in file.key -outform pem -nocrypt -out file.pem" to convert to compatible pkcs8 format

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the `\n` in the middle of the key as well?

Comment: @Nepoxx: The [bouncycastle base64 decoder](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Base64.html#decode(java.lang.String)) that I'm using ignores whitespace.

Comment: Maybe you should add clarification in your answer that it works with PKCS#8 format

Comment: GOD bless you Bro , after 4 days of pain of Microsoft key generation system i found it's "modulus | exponent , ... " structure . so i must convert it to PEM>DER structure (the standard of) then i used your code and i just crying , really bad pain was !! , Thank you so so  much , Thank you BouncyCastle

Answer (score 24):

The problem you'll face is that there's two types of PEM formatted keys: PKCS8 and SSLeay. It doesn't help that OpenSSL seems to use both depending on the command:

The usual `openssl genrsa` command will generate a SSLeay format PEM. An export from an PKCS12 file with `openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12` will create a PKCS8 file.

The latter PKCS8 format can be opened natively in Java using `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`. SSLeay formatted keys, on the other hand, can not be opened natively.

To open SSLeay private keys, you can either use BouncyCastle provider as many have done before or Not-Yet-Commons-SSL have borrowed a minimal amount of necessary code from BouncyCastle to support parsing PKCS8 and SSLeay keys in PEM and DER format: http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pkcs8.html. (I'm not sure if Not-Yet-Commons-SSL will be FIPS compliant)

### Key Format Identification

By inference from the OpenSSL man pages, key headers for two formats are as follows:

**PKCS8 Format**

Non-encrypted: `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`
Encrypted: `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`

**SSLeay Format**

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

(These seem to be in contradiction to other answers but I've tested OpenSSL's output using `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`. Only PKCS8 keys, showing `----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` work natively)

Comment: I believe you can use openssl commands to convert "raw" keys into the equivalent PKCS8 output. Try something like openssl pkcs8 -topk8

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing your observations of PEM files. It can take a while to figure the same.

Answer (score 20):

Parsing PKCS1 (only PKCS8 format works out of the box on Android) key turned out to be a tedious task on Android because of the lack of ASN1 suport, yet solvable if you include [Spongy castle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) jar to read DER Integers.

```
String privKeyPEM = key.replace(
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "")
    .replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

// Base64 decode the data

byte[] encodedPrivateKey = Base64.decode(privKeyPEM, Base64.DEFAULT);

try {
    ASN1Sequence primitive = (ASN1Sequence) ASN1Sequence
        .fromByteArray(encodedPrivateKey);
    Enumeration<?> e = primitive.getObjects();
    BigInteger v = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();

    int version = v.intValue();
    if (version != 0 && version != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong version for RSA private key");
    }
    /**
     * In fact only modulus and private exponent are in use.
     */
    BigInteger modulus = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger publicExponent = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger privateExponent = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger prime1 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger prime2 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger exponent1 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger exponent2 = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();
    BigInteger coefficient = ((DERInteger) e.nextElement()).getValue();

    RSAPrivateKeySpec spec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
} catch (IOException e2) {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

Comment: Spongy castle and Bouncy castle jar's arent FIPS compliant, Infact I looked into Bouncy Castle provider long back but it would not fit into my requirements as its not FIPS compliant.

Comment: @VenkatMadhav DER is not an encryption standard - it's an encoding standard.

Comment: on a related matter, any examples on handling SSH public keys? I am guessing only 3 lines need to be changed. read from the public key file ("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"), "kf.generatePublic" and "spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);"?

Comment: Been working through this all night (and several attempts before). While ugly compared to modern java standards, this is by far the best way to read SSL private keys (such as `~/.ssh/id_rsa`)

Comment: The key actually listed in the question is PKCS#8, this code won't parse it.

Answer (score 5):

As others have responded, the key you are trying to parse doesn't have the proper PKCS#8 headers which Oracle's `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` needs to understand it. If you don't want to convert the key using `openssl pkcs8` or parse it using JDK internal APIs you can prepend the PKCS#8 header like this:

```
static final Base64.Decoder DECODER = Base64.getMimeDecoder();

private static byte[] buildPKCS8Key(File privateKey) throws IOException {
  final String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(privateKey.toPath()));
  if (s.contains("--BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--")) {
    return DECODER.decode(s.replaceAll("-----\\w+ PRIVATE KEY-----", ""));
  }
  if (!s.contains("--BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY--")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid cert format: "+ s);
  }

  final byte[] innerKey = DECODER.decode(s.replaceAll("-----\\w+ RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", ""));
  final byte[] result = new byte[innerKey.length + 26];
  System.arraycopy(DECODER.decode("MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKY="), 0, result, 0, 26);
  System.arraycopy(BigInteger.valueOf(result.length - 4).toByteArray(), 0, result, 2, 2);
  System.arraycopy(BigInteger.valueOf(innerKey.length).toByteArray(), 0, result, 24, 2);
  System.arraycopy(innerKey, 0, result, 26, innerKey.length);
  return result;
}
```

Once that method is in place you can feed it's output to the `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` constructor like this: `new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(buildPKCS8Key(privateKey));`

Comment: But that doesn't change the PKCS#1 data to PKCS#8.

Comment: @user207421: yes it does; that base64 blob is the outer tag & (dummy) len, version, AlgorithmIdentifier for RSA, and inner tag & (dummy) len which, after the len fields are corrected, makes PKCS1-private into PKCS8-RSA.

Answer (score -1):

For someone looking for an easier way to convert RSAPrivateKey to PrivateKey, BouncyCastle has a `KeyUtil` to do this.

```
  RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = RSAPrivateKey.getInstance(pkcs1Bytes)
  byte[] privateKeyInfoBytes = KeyUtil.getEncodedPrivateKeyInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption, DERNull.INSTANCE), rsaPrivateKey);
  PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyInfoBytes);
  PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

If the PKCS1 PEM input is encrypted with let's say AES 256 CBC, it could be decrypted with a `JcePemDecryptorProvider`

```
PEMDecryptor decryptor = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder().build("password").get("AES-256-CBC");
byte[] decrypted = decryptor.decrypt(pkcs1Bytes, iv);
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your id_rsa file doesn't have any extension like .txt or .rtf. Rich Text Format adds additional characters to your file and those gets added to byte array. Which eventually causes invalid private key error. Long story short, Copy the file, not content.