# How to get the java.security.PrivateKey object from RSA Privatekey.pem file?

Tags: java, ssl, jca, jsse

I have a RSA private key file (OCkey.pem). Using java i have to get the private key from this file. this key is generated using the below openssl command. 
Note : I can't change anything on this openssl command below.

```
openssl> req -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -keyout OCkey.pem -out OCreq.pem -subj "/C=country/L=city/O=OC/OU=myLab/CN=OCserverName/" -config req.conf
```

The certificate looks like below.

> /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
>   bash-3.00$ less OCkey.pem 
>   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
>  Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
>  DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,EA1DBF8D142621BF
>
> BYyZuqyqq9+L0UT8UxwkDHX7P7YxpKugTXE8NCLQWhdS3EksMsv4xNQsZSVrJxE3
>   Ft9veWuk+PlFVQG2utZlWxTYsUVIJg4KF7EgCbyPbN1cyjsi9FMfmlPXQyCJ72rd
>   ...
>  ...
>   cBlG80PT4t27h01gcCFRCBGHxiidh5LAATkApZMSfe6BBv4hYjkCmg== 
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Following is what I tried

```
byte[] privKeyBytes = new byte[(int)new File("C:/OCkey.pem").length()]; 
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes));
```

but getting

> "java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format"

Please help.

Comment: Make sure the privatekey is in DER format and you're using the correct keyspec. I believe you should be using PKCS8 here for the privkeybytes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure the privatekey is in DER format and you're using the correct keyspec. I believe you should be using PKCS8 here for the privkeybytes

Firstly, you need to convert the private key to binary DER format.
Heres how you would do it using [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/):

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem -out private_key.der -nocrypt
```

Finally,

```
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename) throws Exception {

        File f = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        dis.readFully(keyBytes);
        dis.close();

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }
```

Comment: I have been looking for a way to solve this for some days. Great solution. However the PEM parameter did not work for me, but skipping it dit not cause problems.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you forgot to include the import statement at the beginning of your solution.