# Decrypt an encrypted private key file with passphrase - java

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, ssl-certificate, private-key

I have an encrypted private key file lib below.

```
String privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                     Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
                     DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,XXXX 
                     ..................
                     .............."
```

I want to decrypt this private key using a decryption password, i have the password. In openssl something like this helps me decrypt

```
openssl rsa -aes256 -in encrypted_private.key -out /tmp/mydecrptyedkey.key -passin pass:decryption_passphrase
```

How do i do this in Java, found some posts which had used BountyCastle but am i do see there are known CVE with the library. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276820/decrypting-an-openssl-pem-encoded-rsa-private-key-with-java

Comment: @KellyMarchewa: Looks like a dup in fact.