# Android Market In-App Billing Private Key (RSA)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, key, google-play

I want to implement In-App Billing in my application. I have a private key (provided by Google) to verify requests, but i need to put it inside a .pem file. The problem is that when I paste it in the form:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
------------<MY KEY>----------
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

It says that is an invalid certificate.

How can I transform the Key string in a valid .pem file? Thanks.

Comment: You can refere to this ansewer, please see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216969/getting-rsa-private-key-from-pem-base64-encoded-private-key-file

Answer (score 1):

What is provided by Google is not private but a *public* key. The private key resides on Google's servers. What language/libraries are you using? You probably need a PEM *public key* file, which goes something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<PASTE HERE>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that it says that the key must have 256 characters instead of 363. Google gave me that key, so I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Again, how and with library/language are you trying to parse the key? Paste the full error message or stack trace.

Comment: java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 344 but was expecting 256
 at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:189)
 at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1172)
 at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:623)
 at com.estontorise.simplersa.RSAToolImpl.verifyWithKey(RSAToolImpl.java:101)

Comment: The code that brings out that exception is: tool.verifyWithKey(data, signature, publicKey);

Comment: This is a signature verification exception, not a key parsing exception. Show how you parse the key and/or the full code.

Comment: I'm using RSATool to verify the signature. sslSecurityService.verify(purchaseData.getData().getBytes(), purchaseData.getSignature().getBytes()); and then in the verify method: tool.verifyWithKey(data, signature, publicKey); tool is an instance of RSATool

Comment: You are aware that there is no way for us to divine what's inside `RSATool`, right? Either post your full code or a link to the library(s) you are using. If you just give us the names of your methods, no one can really help you.

Comment: I thought that RSATool was a common library for doing that. Here's a link http://code.google.com/p/simplersalibrary/ . It uses the BouncyCastle provider

Comment: Never heard of it and don't how popular it is. It seems you are passing wrong signature data: the signature you get from Google Play is Base64 encoded, you need to decode it, before you can pass it to `RSATool.verify()` which expects the raw signature as a `byte[]`. For a 2048-bit key the signature key is 256 bytes long (2048/8).