# Read RSA private key of format PKCS1 in JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, rsa, bouncycastle

Is it possible to read the RSA private key of format PKCS1 in JAVA without converting to PKCS8? if yes, sample code is appreciated.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 BASE64 ENCODED DATA
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Java does not come with out-of-the-box support for PKCS1 keys. You can however use [Bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org)

```
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(privateKeyFile));
JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
Object object = pemParser.readObject();
KeyPair kp = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
```

Comment: I got an error: `java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC`

Comment: I solved it by adding `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`

Comment: @pedrofb ....    I am trying this in android I cannot resolve `PEMParser` and `JcaPEMKeyConverter` .... I tried using `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.55` ... but didn't work .... Which Jar I need to use or which grade do I need to use for this ?

Comment: You will need `bcpkix` and `bcprov`. Try with  `compile "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:$bouncycastleVersion"    compile "org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:$bouncycastleVersion"`

Comment: Here is a solution without Bouncycastle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339208/975386

Comment: With most Java (at least Oracle and OpenJDK) technically you don't need to `set` or have configured the BC provider; JcaPEMKeyConverter works fine with the default provider(s). But you do need the bcprov _jar_ because BC's asn1 classes are in it, and given you have the jar you might as well use the provider classes.

Comment: This code throws exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder cannot be cast to class org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair (org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder and org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Comment: This method doesn't work. I used Java 20.

Comment: @Nambi: you tried to read a file that contains a certificate, not a PKCS1 (actually any OpenSSL-legacy) private key. This question and answer is only for reading a PKCS1/legacy private key, not a certificate, and not anything else that isn't a PKCS1/legacy private key. It does work for a correct file, in any Java version.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76766993/184201), there is a solution without `BouncyCastle`.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Pkcs1ToPkcs8 {
  private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = """
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAkiAWsNL5sQqkDi04soEEOGiZQ7LlB91Z3jh1uHFByXXixHVC
      VwuahgAWxJ345G6AZVqgPxLnopPh513kXTPWRMggC6HszU+jQp3fkNo7OnzMhQcP
      ...
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      """;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var pem = PRIVATE_KEY
        .replaceAll("-----.+KEY-----", "")
        .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

    var bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pem);
    bytes = buildPkcs8KeyFromPkcs1Key(bytes);
    var keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    var keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
    var privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    System.out.println(privateKey);
  }

  private static byte[] buildPkcs8KeyFromPkcs1Key(byte[] innerKey) {
    var result = new byte[innerKey.length + 26];
    System.arraycopy(Base64.getDecoder().decode("MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKY="), 0, result, 0, 26);
    System.arraycopy(BigInteger.valueOf(result.length - 4).toByteArray(), 0, result, 2, 2);
    System.arraycopy(BigInteger.valueOf(innerKey.length).toByteArray(), 0, result, 24, 2);
    System.arraycopy(innerKey, 0, result, 26, innerKey.length);
    return result;
  }
}
```