# Instantiate java.security classes PrivateKey and X509Certificate from .key and .cer files

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

**The original goal is:**

Generate a https url where one of parameters is PKCS7 detached signature (RSA, SHA-256, UTF-8, BASE64).

**What do I have:**

1. private key (.key file begin with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
   end like this "kIng0BFt5cjuur81oQqGJgvU+dC4vQio+hVc+eAQTGmNQJV56vAHcq4v
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----")
2. self signed certificate (.cer file begin with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----",
   end like this "xwRtGsSkfOFL4ehKn/K7mgQEc1ZVPrxTC7C/g+7grbKufvqNmsYW4w==
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----")
3. data to sign

I found a java code that do almost what I need.

Method signature:

```
 public static String sign(PrivateKey privateKey,
                           X509Certificate certificate,
                           String data);
```

Now I'm stuck on how to get PrivateKey and X509Certficiate classes from given files.

I looked at many examples and got confused by these moments:

1.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
```

or

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
```

Didn't find alternatives for PKCS7 standard.

2. A snippet of method that builds PrivateKey using bouncycastle library:

   ```
       inputStream = Files.newInputStream(privateKeyFile.toPath());
       reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       pemParser = new PEMParser(reader);
       PEMDecryptorProvider decryptorProvider = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder()
               .setProvider(PROVIDER)
               .build(privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
       PEMEncryptedKeyPair encryptedKeyPair = (PEMEncryptedKeyPair) pemParser.readObject();
       PEMKeyPair keyPair = encryptedKeyPair.decryptKeyPair(decryptorProvider);
       ...
   ```

In this example I have to provide some privateKeyPassword to PEMDecryptorProvider. What is the point of this password and where can I get it?

From keyPair value I can get both privateKey and publicKey.

What is the connection between publicKey from PEMKeyPair and my certificate ? Are they the same?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try ```Key RSAKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"). generatePrivate(new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));```

Comment: @zhh: you can't generate a private key from an X509EncodedKeySpec.

Comment: The file extensions `.key`.and `.cer` are not particularly meaningful. What matters is the format of the contents of these files, not the file extensions themselves. Is the private key encrypted? Is it base-64 encoded? Does the  `.key` file start out like `-----BEGIN <something>`?  Does the `.cer` file start out that way also?

Comment: @JamesKPolk, Hey! I updated the post, yes the private key and certificate is base-64 encoded, both start out like ---- BEGING <something>.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: >> "Is the private key encrypted?"
I don't really know. How to figure it out? I added the last line of the key's body.

Comment: run `openssl rsa -in private.key`. If the command asks you for a password then the file is encrypted. If it completes successfully without asking for a password then it's *not* encrypted.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953072/238704) shows how to read in your private key.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need bouncycastle to read in the public key as Java's CertificateFactory directly supports the format of your .cer file.

The private key appears to be in a PKCS1 format that openssl can produce. If you wish to keep that format [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953072/238704) shows how to extract the private key. Combining the two, here is a short snippet to read in a certificate and a private key.

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class Main {

    private static PrivateKey readPrivateKey(String filename) throws Exception {
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(filename));
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        PEMKeyPair pemKeyPair = (PEMKeyPair) pemParser.readObject();
        KeyPair kp = converter.getKeyPair(pemKeyPair);
        return kp.getPrivate();
    }

    private static X509Certificate readCertificate(String filename) throws Exception {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        return (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(filename));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        PrivateKey privateKey = readPrivateKey("myKey.priv");
        X509Certificate cert = readCertificate("mycert.cer");
    }
}
```