# Using Spring Security OAUTH2 with JWT Bearer entitlement string in the WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

Update: I found the below question that is like mine.  The solution offered does use a filter for authentication, however, like it says in the comments, it doesn't use the any of the other features of Spring Security, like the repos to cache the credentials.  For my product I'll be making hundreds of calls a minute and so really need to cache the AuthN token so I don't swamp the token server.

[OAuth 2 client for JWT bearer grant using Spring OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782653/oauth-2-client-for-jwt-bearer-grant-using-spring-oauth?rq=2)

---

I'm attempting to create a sample application which uses Springs WebClient to make a call to a service that requires OAUTH2 authentication with a grant_type of urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer.  Instead of providing a clientId and secret a Jwt credentials entitlement is required. I have gotten the entitlement out-of-band as a file that is in my resource's directory.

I was able to create a simple manual call to the token server and to resource server with the token and that all works.  Now I'd like to use a Spring Security filter with the WebClient to automatically manage getting a new auth token when it expires.

My question is how to add my entitlement string to the request that Spring Security makes to the token server? I know how to load the file into a string, etc.  I don't know where I need to put it to get it in the request body.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder wcBuilder, ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction   oauth =
          new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
           
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("restiq");
        
        return wcBuilder
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                          ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        JwtBearerReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                new JwtBearerReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider();
                
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

My application.properties file contains:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.restiq.client-id=restiq-client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.restiq.authorization-grant-type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.restiq.scope={my target server}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.restiq.provider=restiq

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.restiq.token-uri=https://auth-server.{my domain}.com/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.restiq.jwk-set-uri=https://auth-server.{my domain}.com/.well-known/jwks.json
```

I'm using Spring Security v.5.7.9 which says that it supports JWT Bearer tokens for WebClients.  But the docs appear a little thin.  All the examples I've found have been for using OAUTH2 with a credential grant (client id/secret).  Does anyone have an example for how to make a WebClient that talks to a server with a Jwt-Bearer type grant using a Spring Security filter?

-Richard

Comment: Did you find any solution for this yet? I am facing the same issue.