# is PKCS8EncodedKeySpec capable to read both PKCS1 and PKCS8 private key

Tags: java, rsa, private-key, jce, pkcs#8

Although the title is a question but I just managed to do this with the same code, while I am just not sure whether `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` is designed to do this job, or my private key is generated by accident to make this work(key generated by `openssl`).

my code(`pemPath` is pem type private key file path):

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pemPath))) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.startsWith("--")) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
    }

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec priPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringBuilder.toString()));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(priPKCS8);
}
```

And also I paste PKCS1 file content:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and PKCS8 file content:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

By the way, both private keys succeed to decrypt the same cipher text.
And the openssl command:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa_private_key_2048.pem 2048
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in rsa_private_key_2048.pem -out pkcs8_rsa_private_key_2048.pem -nocrypt
```

Comment: Java has no support to load pkcs1 keys. How do you loaded it?

Comment: @pedrofb I have pasted my code, just ignore the `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` line, then concatenate the other string, decode the final string with base64 tool to byte array which will be the param of `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` constructor. Just to clarify, I am using java8.

Comment: Running your example with java8 and `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` key throws `Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence`. Ensure you are reading the correct file, because you shouldn't be able to load pkcs1 key

Comment: @pedrofb, thanks for your test, I just find that I have a static statement `static { Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); }` which is used for other purpose, it seems to have an impact on the default behavior. After I delete the statement, I get the same error in your comment.

Comment: Bouncycastle is able to load PCKS#1 keys, so your code was using BouncyCastle cryptographic provider instead of JVM default. Summarizing, to load a pkcs1 key you can convert it to pkcs8 using openssl or use Bouncycastle

Comment: Check `KeyFactory.getInstance` code, it will iterate over the available providers, during the process there would be exception but would be caught until the capable provider found or the last provider reached. That should be the reason why adding `BouncyCastleProvider` works.

Comment: Ok, it is clear now

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339208/975386

Answer (score -1):

What if the private key in PEM format(PKCS#1 format)string being passed in a json payload input. PKCS8EncodedKeySpec  is currently working for both PKCS#1 and PKCS#8. The provider is SunRsaSign.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)