# BouncyCastle openssl cannot be resolved

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I wanted to code from this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580055/1262568) but i have error `The import org.bouncycastle.openssl cannot be resolved`  `The import org.bouncycastle.openssl cannot be resolved` and i have no idea how coudl i repair this becouse other bouncycastle libs are detected correctly.
I will be grateful for any ideas whats wrong. Im using eclipse and i have instaled bouncycastle like in this instruction [itcsoultions](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/22/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-cryptographic-api-in-netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-jse-projects/)

Comment: How are you building your program? Maven? ANT? Raw command line? If so, please show us your build script. Also, what BC components have you installed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In addition to the provider (a.k.a. `bcprov`) and lightweight API, you also need the PKIX API, which provides the `openssl` package.

Either download `bcpkix-jdk15on-150.jar` from [BC downloads page](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) ([direct link](https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-150.jar)) and drop it in the same directory of `bcprov` or add it to your maven dependencies with its coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.50</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Whenever we get error saying "The import *** cannot be resolved", it means that there is problem with library. Here, bcprov-jdk jar is missing.
 I did the following, and it worked for me!
      1. Download bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar from https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html
    2. Right click on **Project-->Properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries tab--> Click on Add         External JARs..** Select the path where you have the dowlnloaded bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar. 
        Then click OK. That's it.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. Still showing the errors in import