# How to create private and public key correctly so that Java can read them?

Tags: openssl, rsa, keystore, pem

I followed following steps from [OpenSSL: Generating an RSA Key From the Command Line](http://rietta.com/blog/2012/01/27/openssl-generating-rsa-key-from-command/).

```
1. openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048
2. openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
3. openssl rsa -in private.pem -out private_unencrypted.pem -outform PEM
```

Now I wanted to read those files using Java code. So write the following code, as per link below code is correct but the file format which I created using above three commands casing the problem. Could anyone please guide me on this?

```java
public class PublicPrivateKeyDemo {
    private static File privateKeyFile = null;
    private static File publicKeyFile = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "E:/Advance Java/AJAX/1";
        privateKeyFile = new File(path + "/" + "private.pem");
        publicKeyFile = new File(path + "/" + "public.pem");

        try {
            loadkeys();
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void loadkeys() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = new byte[(int) publicKeyFile.length()];
        FileInputStream publicFis = null;
        publicFis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);
        if (publicFis.read(publicKeyBytes) > 0) {
            X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) factory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            BigInteger pKeyModulus = pubKey.getModulus();
            BigInteger pKeyExponent = pubKey.getPublicExponent();
            System.out.println("PUBLIC KEY EXPO : "+pKeyExponent);

        }

        byte[] privateKeyBytes = new byte[(int) privateKeyFile.length()];
        FileInputStream privateFis = null;
        privateFis = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile);
        if (privateFis.read(privateKeyBytes) > 0) {
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);
            BigInteger pKeyModulus = privKey.getModulus();
            BigInteger pKeyExponent = privKey.getPrivateExponent();
            System.out.println("PRIVATE KEY : "+pKeyExponent);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to read .pem file to get private and public key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11787571), [How to use .key and .crt file in java that generated by openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6482484), [Using a PEM encoded, encrypted private key to sign a message natively](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1580012), etc. Save the key in ASN.1/DER with `-outform DER` or similar. Use `openssl pkcs8` to convert a PEM encoded key into ASN.1/DER encoded key.

Comment: @jww+ or in 1.0.0 up (since 2010) use `openssl pkey -outform der` to convert to clear pkcs8; then you don't need `-topk8 -nocrypt`, Alternatively use `genpkey` instead of `genrsa` to generate in pkcs8 to start with (and specify `-outform der`).